# Accessing the html elements having same names and values by vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Sir . there are some html buttons which dont have id . i want to access these html buttons which have the same type name and values . But i cant able to access then due to their same names and values . Can u plz guide me about that below is the source code given

```
<FORM NAME='f1' METHOD='post' action='dfassfeed21.php'><INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtid' value='E712050-15'><INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtpsw' value='HH29'><INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtassno' value='1'><INPUT TYPE='SUBMIT' NAME='btnSub' value='Start' style='background-color:#009900; color:#fff;'></FORM>

<FORM NAME='f1' METHOD='post' action='dfassfeed21.php'><INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtid' value='E712050-15'><INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtpsw' value='HH29'><INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtassno' value='2'><INPUT TYPE='SUBMIT' NAME='btnSub' value='Start' style='background-color:#009900; color:#fff;'></FORM>

<FORM NAME='f1' METHOD='post' action='dfassfeed21.php'><INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtid' value='E712050-15'><INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtpsw' value='HH29'><INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtassno' value='1'><INPUT TYPE='SUBMIT' NAME='btnSub' value='Start' style='background-color:#009900; color:#fff;'></FORM>
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
<FORM NAME='f1' METHOD='post' action='dfassfeed21.php'><INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtid' value='E712050-15'><INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtpsw' value='HH29'><INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtassno' value='1'><INPUT TYPE='SUBMIT' NAME='btnSub' value='Start' style='background-color:#009900; color:#fff;'></FORM>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this javascript or CSS? Please be clear in your question.

I assume VB.NET is on the server-side. You cannot use ASP.NET to manipulate elements in the DOM, so I am assuming you are using javascript/CSS. If you want to select an input button with the name **btn1** and the value **abc** then use the following selector:

```
[name=btn1] [value=abc]
```

Note that the value must be alphanumeric.

Then you can further select individual elements using the `nth-child` CSS selector, though only available in CSS3. For example, to select the **second** button matching the above criteria, use the following selector:

```
[name=btn1] [value=abc]:nth-child(2)
```

Comment: Please note that the CSS3 `nth-child` is not supported in IE8 or older